# Add 'first name', 'last name', 'date of birth' and 'terms and conditions' to register fields?

Tags: user-registration

How can I add 'first name', 'last name', 'date of birth' and 'terms and conditions' to WordPress' register fields? My site is adult-themed and I would like to verify users' ages and have them agree to the terms before entering.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding fields**

At first adding some fields to the registering formular

```
add_action( 'register_form', 'extended_register_form', 10, 0 );

function extended_register_form() {

    // if an error occurs, we are here again and the
    // values that are entered in the formular are setup in the $_POST array
    $age = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    echo '<p>';
    echo '<label for="age">Your age:&&nbsp;</label>';
    printf( '<input type="text" id="age" name="age" size="2" value ="%s" />', $age );
    echo '</p>';

    echo '<p>';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="tos_check" name="tos_check" />';
    echo '<label for="tos_check">&nbsp;I agree to the terms of service</label>';
    echo '</p>';

}
```

**Verifying, validating & sanitazion**

Now we have to verify the users input. If one or more values does not match our criteria, we want to throw an error message. To do this, hook into the `registration_errors` and add one or more errors to the error object. If the error object is not empty, the registration will be stopped and the errors will be printed.

```
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'show_errors', 10, 3 );

function show_errors( $errors, $login, $email ) {

    $tos_check = ( isset( $_POST['tos_check'] ) && true == $_POST['tos_check'] ) ?
        true : false;

    if ( false == $tos_check )
        $errors->add( 'termsnotaccepted', 'You have to agree to the TOS' );

    $age_check = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    if ( $age_check < 21 )
        $errors->add( 'toyoungerror', 'Sorry, you are to young' );

    return $errors;

}
```

**Storing the data**

At last hook in the user registering routine and check if the (verified and validated) values are set. If the values are present, store them in the users meta.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'user_register', 10, 1 );

function user_register( $user_id ) {

    $data = array();

    $age = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

    if ( ! empty( $age ) )
      $data['age'] = $age;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'choose-a-key', $data );

    return $user_id;

}
```

**Summary**

1. Add your fields to the registering formular
2. Verify, validate and sanitize the values. If a required value is not set (or not valid), add an error. This will stop the registration process and print the error message
3. Store the needed values in the users meta